# Difference between (parentSelectionChanged) and (selectionChanged) in Ag grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid-angular

I am confused by below ag grid definition.
Could someone explain to me what is the difference between (parentSelectionChanged) and (selectionChanged) in below 2 block of code?

Thanks!

```
 <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <app-atlas-grid
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [floatingFilter]="true"
      [enableFilterComponent]="true"
      [contextMenuItems]="searchGridContextMenu"
      [pagination]="true"
      (parentSelectionChanged)="onSelectionChangedGrid($event)"
      (parentOnGridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      [paginationPageSize]=20
      [context]="context"
      style="height: 720px;"
    >
    </app-atlas-grid>
  </div>

 <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <app-atlas-grid
      [rowData]="rowData"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [floatingFilter]="true"
      [enableFilterComponent]="true"
      [contextMenuItems]="searchGridContextMenu"
      [pagination]="true"
      (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChangedGrid($event)"
      (parentOnGridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      [paginationPageSize]=20
      [context]="context"
      style="height: 720px;"
    >
    </app-atlas-grid>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of `ag-grid`you're using but in `21.x` the `parentSelectionChanged` isn't actually a method. I would imagine you're using a version where they both exist but one is deprecated.

You can always go look in the `node_modules` folder at the actual code in ag grid to see what comments / jsdocs the methods have on them. A lot of IDEs offer the ability for you to control + click methods / properties to jump to their definition, including in node module dependencies